# touchXML: stringValue not saved as string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, touchxml

```
        NSLog(@"Status: %@", [[[xmlElement elementsForName:@"status"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]);
        NSString *val = [[[xmlElement elementsForName:@"status"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        if (val == @"error")
        {
```

This is my log 2011-07-02 16:09:40.565 Revistero[994:207] Status: error

However it doesn't enter the if

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`isEqualToString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

```
    if ([val isEqualToString:@"error"])
    {
```